# "ARIA role must be appropriate for the element" on html/head/body

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

Whilst running the aXe accessibility tool in Chrome Developer, I am getting the following error on my `head` and `body` elements

> ARIA role must be appropriate for the element

My HTML is as follows..

```
<html>
<head role="banner">
...
</head
<body role="main">
...
</body>
```

If I remove the roles, I get an error saying a page must have a landmark role but if I add main back to either html, head or body, I still get the error

What are the acceptable ARIA roles for head and body that also relate to a landmark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What are the acceptable ARIA roles for head and body that also relate to a landmark?

There aren't any.

Your landmarks should be *inside* the body element.

The W3C [provide some examples](https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_ARIA_landmarks_to_identify_regions_of_a_page).

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add to the previous answer that you have probably made a confusion between *head* and *header*.

*Banner* is a possible appropriate role for an *header* element.
The header should itself be present inside the body.

In the opposite, informations in the *head* element (except title) aren't supposed to be shown on screen and be present in the accessibility tree.
Thus they musn't have a role; that wouldn't make sense.